# Обработать запросы Post и Get в JavaScript

Tags: post, javascript, get

Этим кодом я получаю текст исходник сайта. Мне нужно узнать некоторые данные, ак можно из этого текста, их? Писать обработчик для анализа страницы ?

P.S. этот код выполняется не на сайте

```
var url = "http://www.site.com";
var req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
req.open("GET", url, true);
req.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        // для статуса "OK"
        if (req.status == 200) {
            alert(req.responseText); // печатает текст сайта
        } else {
            alert("Не удалось получить данные: " + req.statusText);
        }
    }
} 
req.send(null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если текст и данные имеют всегда одинаковую структуру, то вам нужно использовать регулярные выражения для "вытаскивания" определенных фрагментов текста

Answer (score 6):

Во первых данный код с горем пополам будет работать только в эксплорере, не?
Используйте jQuery для всего этого. Код будет выглядеть примерно так.

```
function parse_data(data){
    var strInputCode = data;
strInputCode = strInputCode.replace(/&(lt|gt);/g, function (strMatch, p1){
        return (p1 == "lt")? "<" : ">";
    });
    var strTagStrippedText = strInputCode.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
return(strTagStrippedText);

}

$.ajax({
      url: 'www.site.com',
      success: function(data) {
        /* отсюда вызываете свою функцию передавая ей параметр data, содержащий страницу, которую вы запросили в url */
      parse_data(data);
      }
    });
```

Он возьмет страницу с www.site.com передаст ее в функцию parse_data() с параметром - полученной страницей, а parse_data удалит все теги html из нее. Надеюсь доступно.

Comment: Я писал что этот код выполняется не на сайте, тоисть не в браузере. 
>P.S. этот код выполняется не на сайте
:)
Я уже решил этот вопрос. Всем спасибо.